# field wysiwyg acf missing p in post content (wordpress with twig)

Tags: php, wordpress, twig

I created a Wysiwyg field with ACF, when I fill this field in my page with texts having paragraphs, these are removed and replaced by " " when I display them, can someone help me above ?

This is how I display :

```
<div class="content-description">
  {{  post.custom.content }}
</div>`
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added wpautop and everything is good now

```
<div class="content-description">
  {{  post.custom.content|wpautop }}
</div>
```